# Rewire not importing local directories

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am using Rewire in Node.JS 12, and it works fine when rewiring global modules, i.e. `this.mysql = rewire('mysql')` works fine. However, when I do `this.mod1 = rewire('./mod1')` it errors out with `Cannot find module './mod1'`.

What can possibly have gone wrong? Please note that I have my files inside an `src/` directory, so `node_modules/..` is not my file's directory. I have tried `rewire('./src/mod1')` and it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rewire` works in the same way as `require` so I'm going to assume that you're calling the function (rewire) from a different directory to your mod1 module.

Assuming you have the following file structure:

```
.
├── index.js
├── mod0.js
└── src
|   ├── mod1.js
|   └── dir
|       ├── mod2.js
|       └── anotherDir
|           └── mod3.js
```

When requiring mod1 into **mod2**, the path should be **relative to mod2**:

```js
// src/dir/mod2.js
const mod1 = rewire('../mod1') // NOT rewire('./mod1')
const mod0 = rewire('../../mod0')
const mod3 = rewire('./anotherDir/mod3')
```

Comment: Ahhh, now I see: I have done this recently in the top of my file: `const {sinon, rewire} = require('../test/common');` so obviously rewire is now counting from the `test` directory... Is there any way to retain the above obtaining the `rewire` from `common`, but still make the dir that `rewire` sees the same as the current of the test file (which is not inside the `test` directory)?

Comment: How are you exporting rewire in your common.js? And any reason for having rewire inside common? Why not just `const rewire = require('rewire')` in every module which needs it?

Comment: Well, code repetition is bad practice, so I have that require in the common file, like other `chai.use(blah)` etc.

Comment: Personally I don't think that's code repetition - but that's a separate conversation :) How are you exporting rewire in common.js?

Comment: `const rewire = require('rewire'); module.exports = { rewire };`

Comment: So, any ideas as to why it could easily get the directory of the current file, and not where it got `require`-d?

Comment: You could use `__dirname`. Not sure it's the best option but it would work. `this.mod1 = rewire(__dirname + '/mod1')` instead of `this.mod1 = rewire('./mod1')`